# Oracle PK index extremely low performance

Tags: oracle, index, performance, oracle-11g, query-performance

There's a table `MYHIST` containing 42M rows.

The table has a primary key column `MYHIST_ID NUMBER(22)` with a valid index `PK_MYHIST` on it, and 50 more columns (of types VARCHAR2, NUMBER and DATE), which seems to be not interesting regarding this topic.

Suppose, that statistics for the table (and it's PK index) has been gathered 5 minutes ago.

```
select index_name, table_name, index_type, num_rows, distinct_keys, sample_size, status
  from user_indexes
 where table_name = 'MYHIST';

 INDEX_NAME | TABLE_NAME | INDEX_TYPE | NUM_ROWS | DISTINCT_KEYS | SAMPLE_SIZE | STATUS
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  PK_MYHIST |    MYHIST  |    NORMAL  | 42297450 |    42297450   |    42297450 | VALID
```

Unexpectedly, the simplest query with a filter by `MYHIST_ID` ends with full scan. It's guaranteed that no more than 1000 rows in the table having `MYHIST_ID > 4615200`.

```
    select *
      from MYHIST t
     where MYHIST_ID > 4615200
     order by MYHIST_ID desc;

    Plan:

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation            | Name    | Rows     | Bytes       | Cost    | Time     |
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |         | 38067431 | 14655960935 | 3872743 | 12:54:33 |
    |   1 |   SORT ORDER BY      |         | 38067431 | 14655960935 | 3872743 | 12:54:33 |
    | * 2 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL | MYHIST  | 38067431 | 14655960935 |  746842 | 02:29:23 |
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
    ------------------------------------------
    * 2 - filter("MYHIST_ID">4615200)
```

With an index hint the plan appears to be even worse.

```
    select /*+ index(t PK_MYHIST) */ *
      from MYHIST t
     where MYHIST_ID > 4615200
     order by MYHIST_ID desc;

    Plan:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                      | Name       | Rows     | Bytes       | Cost    | Time     |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |            | 38067431 | 14655960935 | 9274232 | 30:54:51 |
    |   1 |   SORT ORDER BY                |            | 38067431 | 14655960935 | 9274232 | 30:54:51 |
    |   2 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | MYHIST     | 38067431 | 14655960935 | 6148331 | 20:29:40 |
    | * 3 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN           | PK_MYHIST  | 38067431 |             |   85356 | 00:17:05 |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
    ------------------------------------------
    * 3 - access("MYHIST_ID">4615200)
```

**Could you explain what causes the situation, when the index doesn't give an expected performance?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there are more than 10% of the rows with access("MYHIST_ID">4615200), a full table scan is the fastest way to select them.

If you would try a much higher number (eg. "MYHIST_ID">46152000), Oracle's optimizer may prefer using that index.

Comment: Actually, yes I've just found that the last zero in the number was lost during my manipulations. So my question is a dumb one, but you've provided a completely correct and simple reason.

Comment: I was afraid that was what happened.  PS. watch the number of rows in the plan.